# PhpStorm is not opening on my Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: phpstorm, ubuntu-14.04

PhpStorm was running fine till this morning but suddenly it has stopped working. Since the IDE was not loading at all I decided to reinstall it.

The first step was I used the following command to remove the application

```
$ sudo rm -R ~/Phpstorm*
```

Then I downloaded version `2016.1` from https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Previous+PhpStorm+Releases and followed the instruction as shown in this article:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/install-and-set-up-product.html

But neither any launcher icon was created nor I am able to find PhpStorm in application search.

Running `$ ./phpstorm.sh` in terminal window gives me

> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m;
>   support was removed in 8.0

The above message is familiar to me because it used to come every time I run PhpStorm from terminal.

But after reinstall, the message is appearing but the application does not start.

### Edit

Content of `/usr/share/applications/phpstorm.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=5.0.4
Name=JetBrains PhpStorm
# Only KDE 4 seems to use GenericName, so we reuse the KDE strings.
# From Ubuntu's language-pack-kde-XX-base packages, version 9.04-20090413.
GenericName=Text Editor

Exec=phpstorm
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/PhpStorm-145.1616.3/bin/webide.png
Type=Application
Categories=TextEditor;IDE;Development
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=NewWindow

[NewWindow Shortcut Group]
Name=New Window
Exec=phpstorm
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

Reference article:
https://blog.shaharia.com/create-phpstorm-luncher-and-terminal-command-on-ubuntu

Comment: do you see the toolbox? can you start phpstorm from there?

Comment: No, I don't see the toolbox in launcher. It is not in application search console as well. I have added the content of my phpstorm.desktop file.

Comment: try uninstall all and install again via https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox/app/

Comment: Please suggest me the right way to uninstall the application completely.

Comment: Delete PhpStorm directories, listed in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/tuning-the-ide.html#default-dirs

Comment: @Ástþór please tell me where can I find these directories in Ubuntu! :(

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.